# Como criar uma tabela de preços responsiva?

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout-responsivo, table

Preciso criar uma tabela de preço responsiva, mas não sei como começar. Não sei se uso lista ou table.

Abaixo um exemplo de como é pra ficar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem alguma idéia?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D+responsive+table+is%3Aq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você poderia estar adaptando [**este modelo**](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/responsive-pricing-table) ao seu gosto, usando a mesma estrutura.

***[DEMO - JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/cYb7v/)***

Comment: Boa @DiegoVieira, esse não tinha visto ainda. Vou tentar adapta-la.

Comment: Amigo tente minimizar esse código e disponibilizar em sua resposta para que não se perda devido a ser um link externo.

Comment: O código não é meu, apenas coloquei como referência, entretanto, deixarei uma cópia no meu fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode atualizar a propriedade da largura da tabela para 100% onde a depender da tela ele se ajustaria. E para evitar que ao reduzir muito a tela a tabela fique muito estranha você pode definir um tamanho minimo e pode definir também o tamanho máximo da tabela...

```
width: 100%;
min-width: 300px;
max-width: 960px;
```

Talvez isso ajude porem se as demais partes do seu site não forem responsivas não adianta em nada a tabela ser responsiva.